# Pandas multi-index dataframe merge issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

I want to merge two dataframes, df1 and df2, which have multi-index columns :

```
mi1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('id', '0'), ('car', '2018')], names=['variable', 'year'])
mi2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('id', '0'), ('car', '2019')], names=['variable', 'year'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['alice', 1], ['bob', 2]], columns=mi1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['alice', 2], ['bob', 3]], columns=mi2)
```

In both df1 and df2, the first column index refers to a variable name, while the second index refers to a year. Some variables, like 'id' in this example, are not related to a specific year, hence the '0' value, which has no incidence here.

```
df1
variable     id  car
year          0 2018
0         alice    1
1           bob    2

df2
variable     id  car
year          0 2019
0         alice    2
1           bob    3
```

I would like to merge df1 and df2 to get :

```
variable     id  car  car
year          0 2018 2029
0         alice    1    2
1           bob    2    3
```

The problem is that the merge function using the 'id' column, applied to df1 and df2, returns an error message :

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=('id', '0'), how="outer")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 87, in merge
    validate=validate,
  File "C:\Users\AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 652, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "C:\Users\AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1005, in _get_merge_keys
    right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
  File "C:\Users\AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1580, in _get_label_or_level_values
    f"The {label_axis_name} label '{key}' "
ValueError: The column label 'id' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.
```

It is very surprising - and frustrating - because the 'on' paremeter of the merge function has a tuple as argument, so there shouldn't be an issue here.
And I need to use a merge function because in reality, the dataframes to merge are more complex and don't have the same id columns.

Can you tell me how to solve this and merge two dataframes with multi-index columns ?

Comment: Try `on =[('id','0')]`?

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works ! I still wonder why the brackets are needed here, but a least the problem is solved.

Comment: The name of the index level is `('id','0')`, which is an iteratble. You need to wrap it around a list so as pandas interprets it as one column/index-level, else Pandas would understands it as two columns/index-levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `on` can use one or more columns to merge two dataframes

so when you pass `on=('id', '0')` it thinks you want to merge on two fields. Writing `on=[('id', '0')]` removes the ambiguity. One column to merge on and two labels specified as part of the multiindex:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=[('id', '0')], how="outer")
```